# Cannot round Gson Doubles to Longs using Retrofit TypeAdapter in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

Okay my API is giving me a stray `245.00000003` from long ago when it was supposed to only send down whole numbers. I want to make sure I only parse that as a Long with the value of `245`, and make sure if the back end guys do that again I just round it down and then go yell at them.

I have tried numerous type adapters, including the `@JsonAdapter` annotation and the `registerHierarchyTypeAdapter` function and none of them seem to have any effect whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Module
class CoreModule {

    @Provides
    internal fun provideGson(): Gson {
        return GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Long::class.java, LongTypeAdapter()).create()
    }
}

class LongTypeAdapter : TypeAdapter<Long>() {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun read(reader: JsonReader): Long? {
        if (reader.peek() === JsonToken.NULL) {
            reader.nextNull()
            return null
        }
        val stringValue = reader.nextString()

        return try {
            stringValue.toLong()
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            try { stringValue.toDouble().toLong() }
            catch (e: java.lang.NumberFormatException){ 0L }
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun write(out: JsonWriter, value: Long?) {
        if (value == null) {
            out.nullValue()
            return
        }
        out.value(value)
    }
}
```

I assume that code is supposed to examine any Long in my POJO, and when it comes time to matching it to its JSON content, it will return null if it's null, a Long if it can be `toLong()'d`, a Long if it can be `toDouble().toLong()'d`, and 0 otherwise.

POJO:

```
data class OrdersResponse(
    @SerializedName("error") val error: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("message") val message: String,
    @SerializedName("total") val total: Int,
    @SerializedName("orders") val orders: List<Orders>
) {

    data class Orders(
        @SerializedName("id") val id: Long,
        @SerializedName("status") val status: String,
        @SerializedName("completion_time") val completionTime: Long?,
        @SerializedName("total") val total: Long // This is the dodgy value
    ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out, it is confusing because there are several options. 
First of all, the Gson implementation I am providing was not used in the converter factory for Retrofit:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(@Named("baseUrlv1") baseUrl: String, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, gson: Gson): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(LiveDataCallAdapterFactory<Any>())
            .build()
}
```

Secondly, I am only interested in the Long in this Orders object, so instead of having the type adapter look at every single Long, I am using a `JsonDeserializer` ([more info here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-customizing-de-serialization-and-adding-instance-creators-via-jsonadapter)):

```
@Module
class CoreModule {

    @Provides
    internal fun provideGson(): Gson {
        val gson = GsonBuilder()

        gson.registerTypeAdapter(OrdersResponse.Orders::class.java, OrdersDeserializer())

        return gson.create()
    }
}

class OrdersDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<OrdersResponse.Orders> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): OrdersResponse.Orders {
        val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject

        val total = jsonObject.get("total").asNumber.toLong()
        jsonObject.add("total", JsonPrimitive(total))

        return Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, OrdersResponse.Orders::class.java)
    }
}
```